# Inflating a view outside of onCreateView in Fragment

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments, android-inflate

Android docs teach us to inflate our xml layouts in onCreateView and than to return inflated view. But what about inflating in other places?

I want to inflate my view in constructor, store in a filed, and later just return it in onCreateView, already inflated. I can't do it in usual way. For this I must create an Inflater, and it seems to work:

```
class MyFragment : Fragment() 
{
    private var _view: View? = null

    constructor() {
        inflateView()
    }

    private fun inflateView() {
        _view = LayoutInflater.from(requireContext()).inflate(R.layout.my_layout, null, false)
    }

    ...

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        return _view
    }
}
```

But docs say that I must inflate directly in onCreateView(). Why? Are there any drawbacks in this approach? What is the proper way to do this with my requirements?

Comment: From where and when do you call `inflateView()`? It would help to understand *why* you're trying to do this. There are lots of problems you could be creating. For example, when the fragment is recreated by the OS after resuming from the background, there will be a new instance and `_view` will be null again, and `onCreateView` will return null, so you'll have a headless fragment. If a Fragment instance is reused by the system, your original view may be invalidated but you'll be trying to reuse it in the invalid state.

Comment: @Tenfour04, in constructor. Added this info to original question

Comment: Ok, but why are you trying to do this instead of the recommended approach? Need to understand that to be able to answer the very last question in your post. We don’t know what your “requirements” are.

Answer (score 0):

You might have a look at [AsyncLayoutInflater](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/asynclayoutinflater/view/AsyncLayoutInflater).

This will allow for the actual view inflation to happen on a background thread and provides an [OnInflateFinishedListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/asynclayoutinflater/view/AsyncLayoutInflater.OnInflateFinishedListener) callback when inflation is finished.

There are a few restrictions on what can be inflated, so be sure to read the documentation carefully.

Answer (score 0):

Returning **null** from `onCreateView` means you're creating a "headless fragments" (with no UI whatsoever).

This affects its behavior and lifecycle (no `onViewCreated` and `onDestroyView` is called, `viewLifecycleOwner` remains null).

If you intend to create view hierarchy lazily you have to at least return a barebone `FrameLayout` that you will populate later (or just create a "loading" layout and replace it).